# Restrict user groups in Odoo

Tags: odoo, usergroups, access-rights

I have created a module with the model `Workers`. I gave my `Employee` group right access to the `Workers` object to be able to read and write. So the user belonging to the `Employee` group can access every view belonging to the `Worker` object.

However, I have created two different `views/menu items` for my `Workers` object: `HR manager` and `Auditor`. I want only one the `Employee` group to be able to access only the `HR manager` view and not the `Auditor` one.

Basically the codes for the menu items for my two views are as follows:

```
<menuitem action="action_view_HR_Managers" id="menu_HRManager" name="HRManager"></menuitem>
<menuitem action="action_view_Auditors" id="menu_Auditors" name="Auditors"></menuitem>
```

Can I restrict menu items to groups?

Answer (score 0):

To show a menu for a specific group just add groups attribte.

```
 <menuitem..........   groups="first_group, second_group,..."/>
```

In this way only users belong to the list of group can see this menu.

For groups that are defined in other addon you need to specify the addon name and add dependencie in you manifest file.

```
      addon_name.group_name
```